# MySQL. Как максимально легко для базы выбрать запись с самым большим значением? (вопрос оптимизации)

Tags: mysql

Коллеги, доброго времени суток.
Есть таблица обмена данными у которой есть поле priority (может принимать значение от 0 до 100).

Моя задача выбирать всегда записи с самым высоким priority (*Раньше использовал ORDER BY priority DESC*), но когда в базе записей более 15000, то мое ПО начинает захлебываться и извне прилетает больше записей чем я успеваю обработать и таблица забивается и все ложится.

Сейчас отказался от сортировки и делаю *SELECT MAX(priority) FROM ...*, получаю максимальное значение и затем уже вторым запросом получаю все записи с максимальным приоритетом, но может есть возможность как-то легче получать необходимые мне записи с максимальным приоритетом.

Прошу подсказать по оптимизации.

Comment: У Вас есть индекс по ``priority`` ?

Comment: `select ... where priority = (select max(priority) from t)` c индексом на `priority`

Comment: @ValNik я только использую таблицу, но не настраиваю её, но я обязательно уточню этот момент. (это должно как-то ускорить/оптимизировать процесс выборки?)

Comment: @teran благодарю, попробую. (если я правильно понимаю то вложенный запрос должен чуть уменьшить время выборки? или он для базы легче? или и то и другое?)

Comment: вряд ли вы заметите разницу с вложенным запросом и без, но зачем программировать на клиенте отдельную логику, и в целом таскать данные на клиент, отдельно посылать запросы, если это решается все за один раз одним запросом?

Comment: Если таблица маленькая, оптимизация не имеет особого значения. Если начинает иметь значение производительность, при любой форме запроса, уже обязательно иметь индекс.

Comment: @ValNik коллеги сообщают что индекс настроен по двум полям и priority одно из этих полей. Так что, Да, индекс настроен.

Comment: Благодарю всех за комментарии (@teran, @ValNik)
Видимо с выборкой у меня все хорошо и больше оптимизировать в ней нечего.

Comment: @ArchiKu "одно из этих полей" оно так не работает. Чтобы индекс для данного запроса использовался, оно должно быть не одним из, а первым среди этих полей. Так что индекс может быть и настроен, но не факт что для этого запроса.

Comment: в целом вы всегда можете посмотреть `EXPLAIN ...` для данного запроса, там будет указано, используется индекс или нет и какой.